# SQL TO MDX conversion (SUM and Case)

Tags: sql, mdx

I'm having trouble with simple tasks on MDX since I'm new with it. I basically have a fact table with '1' and '0' on two of my columns. I want a new measure where I can get '1' or '0' if both measures = 1, and sum them to a total but I can't get through it.

This is my query, "BOTH" should be the result I want

```
select SUM(ASIGNACION_INICIAL), SUM(INICIADO),
SUM(CASE WHEN ASIGNACION_INICIAL = 1 AND INICIADO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
"BOTH",
ID_CAMARA 
from EST_MAESTRA_CIVIL group by ID_CAMARA;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is more related to SSAS project design then MDX. In you SSAS project, go to dsv, there add a calulated column.In this column will implement your logic defined above. Now in your cube use this calculated column as a measure.

Comment: I see, I actually thought it was possible, I guess I'll have to workaround around it. Thank you!